# SwiftUI always throws argument error for no reason

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

```
struct HomeList: View {
 var body: some View {
  ScrollView { // ERROR HERE: 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments'
   HStack {
    ForEach(0.. < 3) {
     item in
      ScrollView()
    }
   }
   Spacer()
  }
 }
}
```

It always throws the error `Argument passed to call that takes no argument`, only one person has had this issue and they said restarting their project worked for them,

I tried it and the error still gets thrown? Is it a bug or?

Thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call just ScrollView() -> this needs an argument or a content like e.g. so:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView { // ERROR HERE: 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments'
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<3) {
                    item in
                    ScrollView {
                        Text("a")
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, still sends the same error, I tried that anyway too and it still threw the same error

Comment: Ah, found it. Your script helped and it was the correct way, it was also because my function was called 'ScrollView' too which obviously interfered with the ScrollView itself, so I simply just changed the name of the function.